# ioctl failed: Operation not permitted - block layout of my files

Tags: c, linux, unix, ioctl

I want to view the contents of a file at block level.
Given a file, i want to know how many blocks it has and what is the size if each one.

my problem is when i run it i get this error:

```
FIBMAP ioctl failed: Operation not permitted
```

Also when i'm comliling i get the following warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘ioctl’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if (ioctl(fd, FIGETBSZ, &blocksize)) {
```

I am using the following code.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int fd, i, block, blocksize, blkcnt;
    struct stat st;

    assert(argv[1] != NULL);

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd <= 0) {
        perror("error opening file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ioctl(fd, FIGETBSZ, &blocksize)) {
        perror("FIBMAP ioctl failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fstat(fd, &st)) {
        perror("fstat error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    blkcnt = (st.st_size + blocksize - 1) / blocksize;

    for (i = 0; i < blkcnt; i++) {
        block = i;
        if (ioctl(fd, FIBMAP, &block)) {
            perror("FIBMAP ioctl failed");
        }
        printf("%3d %10d\n", i, block);
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please explain me what is the problem in this code.

Comment: Have you checked the `ioctl` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html)

Comment: Yes, i also checked the note that says to use the O_NONBLOCK flag.
I used it but the result is the same

Comment: `FIGETBSZ` is the only ioctl virtual file system case (`do_vfs_ioctl` in kernel code) that calls `put_user()` directly (i.e. copies a buffer from kernel space).  There had been endless discussions about "FIGETBSZ ioctl conflict" on mailing lists but i do not recollect if there has been a solution.  For a start i'd try to make sure i'm calling it on regular files only (`S_ISREG`).  Apart from that, id' try a different kernel version.

Comment: Include `<sys/ioctl.h>` to get rid of that warning.

Answer (score 2):

You should run that program as root.

`ioctl(FIBMAP)` needs the `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` [capability](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

Comment: Better late than never. Thank you!

Comment: @photeesh LOL, I did not notice the date. I'll leave the answer on, anyways. Maybe someone else runs into the same issue.